# Cooldowns in discord.js not giving errors or working

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, discord.js

I am trying to add cooldowns to my handler so I won't have to add the cooldown in every separate command. It isn't sending any errors or responding.

This is in the message event handler:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
//cooldowns
    const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();
    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }
    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;
        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }
    
    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);
    //cooldowns
```

This is the what I'm putting in the command itself:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'tag',
    aliases: ['tags', 't'],
    cooldown: 5,
    category: 'fun',
    description: 'Create a custom command',
    usage: `tag create|delete|edit`,
    run: (client, message, args) => {

    return message.reply('test, command is not done yet this is to test the cooldown')
}}
```

I got the code from here: https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns

Comment: Shouldn't you declare the collections outside of the message event?

Comment: i cant because the event is imported by another handler in index.js, so the event declaration is not in the same file

Comment: OMG i tried declaring the collection outside the module.exports and it worked!

Comment: Alright cool, glad to help

Comment: thanks a lot! I really appreciate it